# HTML/CSS: How do I set the size of this table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

If you visit the link below and add an item to your cart (to make the cart appear in the sidebar), you'll notice that the cart overlaps past the edge of the sidebar widget.

http://savageworkouts.com/2012/05/07/sample-product/

What CSS do I need to write to make the table be the size of it's parent container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write **table-layout:fixed** in your `table.eshop`. write like this:

```
table.eshop {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 99%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the padding on  your `th` and `td` elements:

```
table thead tr th,
table tfoot tr td {
  padding: 8px 10px 9px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}
```

For 0-9 items in the cart, `5` serves as a good padding for the left and right. If you want to go higher, you'll need to push that lower.

```
table thead tr th,
table tfoot tr td {
  padding: 8px 5px 9px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}
```

Another option is to change your font-size. It's really up to you and what you think works without hurting the usability.